# Custom Eclipse plugin deployment with popup contribution to Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have developed a simple plugin to generate some routine code. This plugin has a contribution to a popup menu of Package Explorer. It is working as intended when running from the development environment (`Launch as Eclipse application` from Eclipse RCP) -- an appropriate menu item appears in the menu, and its invocation does what is expected.

However, I'm having a hard time deploying it into a different Eclipse instance.

The developed plugin was exported with Export Wizard, which produced a separate jar file. This jar file has been placed into the dropings directory of another Eclipse installation (newly unpackaged). When this Eclipse instance launches, the popup menu of Package Explorer does not contain the contributed menu item. The information from Eclipse Installation Details shows that the plugin is present on the Plug-Ins tab, and the Configuration tab has it listed as `tg.companion (1.0.0.201208132302) "Companion Object Generator" [Starting]`.

What am I missing? Why the contributed menu item does not show up?

Thanx.

---

The `locationURI` for the menu contribution is `popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer`, the value for property `allPopups` is `true`.

The plugin is unsigned.

---

Here's the plugin files that might shed some light.

Plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="true"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command
               commandId="tg.companion.handler.generator"
               label="TG Create Companion Object"
               style="push"
               tooltip="Creates a companion object to the selected entity object, and provides DAO/RAO implementations">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="tg.companion.handler.GenerateCompanionObjects"
            id="tg.companion.handler.generator"
            name="Generate Comanion">
      </command>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Companion Object Generator
Bundle-SymbolicName: tg.companion;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: tg.companion.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: TG
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.8.1",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.0",
 org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.400"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Command handler:

```
package tg.companion.handler;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragmentRoot;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;

public class GenerateCompanionObjects extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        final Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
        final ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection(event);
        final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) sel;

        final Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
        if (firstElement instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
            createOutput(shell, (ICompilationUnit) firstElement);
        } else {
            MessageDialog.openWarning(shell, "Companion Object Generation Warning", "Please select an entity object for generating a corresponding companion.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void createOutput(final Shell shell, final ICompilationUnit cu) {
         // does code generation work using Java Model
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the error log. Also, are you able check the state of your plug-in in the osgi console - what state is it in?

Comment: Running the ss command printed "427 STARTING    tg.companion_1.0.0.201208141117". Activating the plugin with command start 427, resulted in status ACTIVE. However, no menu contribution appeared.

Comment: There are no errors in the Error Log -- opened from the Windows->Show View.

Comment: are you able to post your plug-in here

Comment: @katsharp Is is possible to attach an archive to the question? Or do you mean post the source of some specific files embedded into the question (e.g. plugin.xml and command class)? Thanx.

Comment: Plug-in xml, command class and manifest might be enough for now

Comment: @katsharp Please find files added to the question. I have removed the source of the createOutput method as it was too long, and should not cause menu contribution not appearing as part of the popup. Thanx a lot for your willingness to assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the problem has been solved!

After careful review of the project structure it was identified that build.properties file (for some reason) did not have plugin.xml checked. As the result, plugin.xml was not included into the produced by the export wizard jar file.

Once the build.properties files has been amended to include plugin.xml, the resulting jar file had it included and deployed without any issues.

Interestingly, the plugin export wizard did not even warn about the exclusion of plugin.xml, which I would personally have expected.